# UI Overlapping Issue in Unity Mixed Reality

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus

**GOAL**

I imported Meta XR Integration package and Meta XR Simulator.
Project platform is Android.

At play mixed reality mode, I want to show UI.

**CONTENT**

I use Built-in and Unity2022.3.8f1. I am using Meta XR Integration 57.0.

I tried show up UI in mixed reality mode but UI is disappear after show UI during few seconds.

But Passthrough is working fine.

How can I fix it?

[OVR Camera Rig Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VezZK.png)

[Passthrough Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ID5Nn.png)

[CenterEyeAnchor Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEJfu.png)